# Discord Bot crashes trying to edit his own messages from another instance

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

So I have a order system that sends embeds incl all important information into a channel.
Whenever an order is started that embed then goes into  "In progress" status by changing its buttons and adding a "Complete" button which then marks the order as completed.
In total the message is sent and edited twice.

Now here's the issue: If the bot ever crashes, due to a server reboot or similar, editing the messages it sent prior to the crash will yield the error:
`(node:6672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot edit a message authored by another user`

Now I can't just go and check if `author.id === client.id` because that'll obviously just return true. So how can I fix that issue? As of now I decided to just add a try catch but I'd rather just add an if clause at the top of the event.

Comment: You are not likely to get a good response with this question. Create the simplest, shortest code example that reproduces the problem. Take a look at [How to write effective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Answer (score 0):

`DiscordAPIError: Cannot edit a message authored by another user` means you are trying to edit another user message
Here's the code for editing bot message:

```js
const msg = await message.channel.send("Will be edit..")
setTimeout(function() {
    msg.edit("Edited")
}, 1000) // will edit the message after 1000 ms (1 second)
```